# Angular 5 refactoring tools for Visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, refactoring

Manually changing one component's name and references is pretty messy - trying to change directories of components is a nightmare. let alone a major refactoring when required.

Is there a decent angular 4+ refactoring tool for Visual Studio Code ?

a plugin or so, which will not only change the name of files but also component selectors and all the import references, and lazy-loaded module names, services, etc - everywhere in the project ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins to do each of the above as a separate but not a complete package available to my best of knowledge.

Otherwise you could quickly integrate angular-cli to generate components and files with the naming conventions and migrate your existing code.

You can also read a good article on **[Refactoring with Visual Studio Code](https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code/)** by John Papa.

Comment: it is a fact that with all GWT other problems, it is still much easier to refactor GWT than Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I use for this 
`Angular Language Service` and `TypeScript Extension Pack` (pack of useful extensions)